# Is there a way to crop screen resolution in windows 7

Tags: windows, display, multiple-monitors, resolution, crop

i'm using a dual monitor setup with a 23,6" monitor and a 24" one. But because one of them is slightly bigger my mouse and other things get off.

Is there a way to make some kind of black bar at the bottom of the 24" screen and still use the 1920x1080 resolution? so it will actually be converted to a 23,6"monitor as well.

The monitor used is an ACER V243HL. As far as I know I can only move the screen up which will make the top part of the screen to move outside my monitor so I can't see that part.

and for Displayfusion, I can't find the option to do this.

I am using an ATI graphics card .

Answer (score 1):

Sure, on most monitors you can do this.  Unfortunately, you haven't specified the monitor models, so I can only give general instructions.  Set the screens to the same resolution in Windows.  Then use what are usually on-screen menu/controls on the larger monitor, and set the image SIZE and/or OFFSET to create the black bar you want.

Answer (score 0):

check for a button on the monitor that you can press to bring up a menu, and look around in that, since I don't know what monitor you have thats the best I can do.

Answer (score 0):

I use [DisplayFusion](http://www.displayfusion.com/) (free). It allows for different monitor resolutions to match-up. Its pretty good.