# How to crop screen resolution? (Acer Monitor, ATI Graphics Card, Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, display, resolution, crop

I have an old monitor that has white edges on all four sides. I don't want my monitor's screen to use a cropped portion of the screen, like this:

[image]

I want the monitor to use only the green portion. I know this question has already been asked ([this question](https://superuser.com/questions/655713/is-there-a-way-to-crop-screen-resolution-in-windows-7?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa), for example), but none of the answers in these questions answer what I want to do.

I'm using a Acer monitor with an ATI graphics card. Answers in other questions suggest:

(a) a solution for NVIDIA graphics cards
(b) solutions that involve keeping a portion of the desktop such as a toolbar on the top (I don't want to do this because I want to crop the monitor on all four sides)
(c) third party software that don't work on my display adapter 
(d) solutions that involve using the monitor's inbuilt menu (that comes up when you press the side buttons) -- I've tried this and all I can do using this option is to crop the sides out, and not the top and bottom, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The free donationcoder utility
[DesktopCoral](http://www.donationcoder.com/software/mouser/other-windows-apps/desktopcoral)
might help :

> DesktopCoral is an unusual program designed to "reserve" some portion
>   of your desktop which is shielded from maximized applications..
>
> Essentially, it acts like an invisible resizeable docking bar, which
>   can be docked to any side of your desktop. This invisible dock acts as
>   a barrier to maximized applications and essentially shields this area
>   of your desktop from other applications.
>
> Within this shielded area you might put certain application windows
>   that you want to be always visible, or you might put one of the many
>   desktop tools like a calendar or system information component.

DesktopCoral can be invoked multiple times and be docked to all the four
corners of the screen. It will not move the taskbar from its position,
so you will need to move it to the least-damaged screen edge.

DesktopCoral can also be invoked by a command line, so you may create a batch
(.bat) file that can reduce the screen by 200 pixels on all sides like this:

```
start DesktopCoral.exe -placement top -dockheight 200
start DesktopCoral.exe -placement bottom -dockheight 200
start DesktopCoral.exe -placement left -dockwidth 200
start DesktopCoral.exe -placement right -dockwidth 200
```

DesktopCoral also has a portable version.